# Flex AdvancedDataGrid - Group By Property of Strongly Typed Object Not Working

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, advanceddatagrid

I have an ArrayCollection of 'Lesson' objects. Each Lesson has the following fields: lessonId, lessonName, topicName. The data may look like this:

```
lessonId = 1, lessonName = Maths, topicName = Basics
lessonId = 2, lessonName = Physics, topicName = Advanced
lessonId = 3, lessonName = English, topicName = Basics
lessonId = 4, lessonName = French, topicName = Advanced
```

I would like to display the data as follows:

```
Basics
    Maths
    English
Advanced
    Physics
    French
```

Keeping it simple to begin with I have tried the following code:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid sortExpertMode="false" width="100%" creationComplete="myGroup.refresh()">

                <mx:dataProvider>
                    <mx:GroupingCollection2 id="myGroup" source="{presenter.lessons}">
                        <mx:Grouping>
                            <mx:GroupingField name="topicName"/>
                        </mx:Grouping>
                    </mx:GroupingCollection2>
                </mx:dataProvider>

                <mx:columns>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="lessonName" />
                </mx:columns>

            </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

I see only the 'lessonName' column but no data or topicName column.

Am I addressing my data source incorrectly? Any thoughts most welcome.

Chris

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex AdvancedDatagrid populating with groupingCollection based on xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975445/flex-advanceddatagrid-populating-with-groupingcollection-based-on-xml)

Comment: I don't know the answer but I can tell you this: grouping does not belong in your dataProvider tags.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. It appears that my code was fine, but I didn't appreciate that when the data source updated this wasn't rippled through to the AdvancedDataGrid. My AdvancedDataGrid was being created before I fetched my data from a MySQL source!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the array collection **presenter.lessons** is **Bindable**.